# Can i use opacity to effect only background of paragraph, not text and other things, just background?

Tags: css

I wanted to know can i use opacity only for background of paragraph or `div` but not to change opacity of text and other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the css `opacity` will render all the stuff inside that particular element invinsible if you set it to `zero` and appear by `1` and if you only want to make the background `transparent` you can use the `rgba()` color type

ex.

```
background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0);
```

`rgba` stands for red, green, blue and alpha, and the `alpha` which is the fourth parameter renders the background to be transparent. its value is from 1 - 100.